# I made a chatting app which is continuosly showing errors

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat, PID: 28266
                                                                                          com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat.FriendlyMessage is missing a constructor with no arguments
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaG(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat.MainActivity$6.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:290)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

Comment: code please? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error message says:

```
com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat.FriendlyMessage is missing a constructor with no arguments
```

So you must be missing a default constructor (constructor with no arguments) in your FriendlyMessage class

Comment: I checked thoroughly through the code nothing as such is missing